# VBA How do offset each item in this toArray?

Tags: excel, vba

I am able to list, into a column of cells, increasing increments of a string...

[image]

BUT...

I need for each string to be placed at an offset of 5 rows from the last. Its not working right.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

It seems to restart the array after every offset instead of offsetting within the array.

```
Set S02_List = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To rndNodeAmount_S02

S02_List.Add ("Sector02_Node0" & i)
            
        Worksheets(17).Range("H4").Resize(S02_List.Count, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(S02_List.toArray)
        Worksheets(17).Range("J4").Offset((5 * i) - 5).Resize(S02_List.Count, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(S02_List.toArray)

Next i
```

This is what im trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Should I 'translate' "to be placed at an offset of 5 rows from the last" in having 5 empty rows between the incremented strings groups? And instead of deducing from your code what you try accomplishing, please better describe it. I mean, do you want obtaining groups of 1, 2, 3, ... up to `rndNodeAmount_S02`, with a gap of 5 empty rows in between?

Comment: Yes, thats correct. 5 rows from the last. But basically 4 empty rows between each.

I've edited the original post to include an image of what im trying to achieve.

Comment: So, you do not need groups (of 1, 2, 3 etc.). Only incremented string with four empty lines in between, would it be a correct understanding? Your question is not so clear if you do not try explaining anything **in words**...

Comment: Yes that is correct. Yeah, sorry, i tried my best to explain it in words as well, but i thought the images would also help.

Comment: OK. The best idea is to not use the range where you want writing. A simple 2D array should be enough. It should be loaded/processed in memory and then its content to be dropped at once where you need. So, where do you need to have it? In column J:J, starting from the fourth row?

Comment: Thats correct - I need it in column J:J starting from the fourth row, please.

Comment: OK. Please, try the code I've just posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the next way. What you tried is incorrect and inefficient, too. I cannot understand what you really took in consideration when design it as you show us. That's why I cannot say anything about a correction way... Was much simpler to me to offer a simple working solution.

Then, no need of any object, but standard VBA:

```
Sub IncrementSpec()
 Dim S02 As Long, strNode As String, necRows As Long, i As Long, k As Long, arr
 
 strNode = "Sector02_Node0"
 S02 = 23  'place here he number of the necessary incremented strings to be placed in the column range
 necRows = (S02 - 1) * 5 + 1 'calculate the necessary rows for the used array
 
 ReDim arr(1 To necRows, 1 To 1): k = 1
 
 For i = 1 To S02 Step 5
    arr(i, 1) = strNode & k: k = k + 1
 Next i
 Range("J4").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).value = arr
End Sub
```

I tried using the pattern you supply, but if nou need another elegant way to place incremented numbers up to 99, without ending in "025", please use the next way:

```
Sub IncrementSpecBis()
 Dim S02 As Long, strNode As String, necRows As Long, i As Long, k As Long, arr
 
 strNode = "Sector02_Node"
 S02 = 23
 necRows = (S02 - 1) * 5 + 1 'calculate the necressary rows for the used array
 
 ReDim arr(1 To necRows, 1 To 1): k = 1
 
 For i = 1 To S02 Step 5
    arr(i, 1) = strNode & Format(k, "00"): k = k + 1
 Next i
 Range("J4").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).value = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: @phoenix Didn't you find some time to test the above answer? If tested, didn't it return as you need/required?